# Eigenvalues of a matrix whose square equals its transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ matrix with $A^2=A^t$. Show that every real eigen value of $A$ is either $ 0$ or $1$

Comment: Does $A^2$ denotes $AA^\top$ or $\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}^2e_ie_j^\top$ ?

Comment: @davcha Usually, $A^2$ means $A\cdot A$, where $\cdot$ means the standard matrix multiplication...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have

$$A^2=A^t\implies (A^t)^2=(A^2)^2=A^4=A$$
hence the polynomial $P=x^4-x=x(x^3-1)=x(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$ annihilates $A$ and then the eigenvalues of $A$ belong to the set of roots  $P$. The real roots are $0$ and $1$.

Comment: For those, who wonder, where $A^4=A$ comes from, note that $A^T=A^2$ implies $A=(A^T)^2$, which is equal to $A^4$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Note that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is the same as the one of $A^t$. Therefore the eigenvalues of $A$ are the same as the ones of $A^t$.